Why do I get this error when trying to run Kuberentes/K3s: "setting cgroup config for procHooks process: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE) failed"
Today I noticed I my Kuberentes/K3s cluster has a problem.
On the node that was defined in my ~/.kube/config file the API server was not running, so I could not use kubectl.
I studied the logfiles and noticed a "token parser error". The file /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.env was empty. I copied the content from another node over and restarted k3s.
After that I could use kubectl again with all nodes, and everything seems "fine", because kubectl get nodes said every node is "ready".
Then I noticed no container/pod could be started on said node.
In /var/log/k3s.log messages appeared related to cgroup:
"Failed to create sandbox for pod" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE) failed: function not implemented: unknown" pod="kube-system/svclb-foo-bar-service-557090fc-4vxc7"

How can I fix this? I have no clue why the k3s.env file was empty or why this cgroup related error occurs.
No difference where found while I compared the worker nodes. With one exception: mount | grep cgroup on the defect node shows only none on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate), while on the other working nodes:
cgroup_root on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755)
openrc on /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,release_agent=/lib/rc/sh/cgroup-release-agent.sh,name=openrc)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cpuset on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cpu on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
cpuacct on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
blkio on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
memory on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
devices on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
freezer on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
net_cls on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
perf_event on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
net_prio on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio)
hugetlb on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
pids on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)

Every node runs Gentoo with a 5.10.144-gentoo kernel.

Update: My colleague has set in /etc/rc.conf to rc_cgroup_mode=hybrid.
After that mount | grep -i cgroup shows on the defect node:
openrc on /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,release_agent=/lib/rc/sh/cgroup-release-agent.sh,name=openrc)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cpuset on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cpu on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
cpuacct on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
blkio on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
memory on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
devices on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
freezer on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
net_cls on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
perf_event on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
net_prio on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio)
hugetlb on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
pids on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)

And now container/pods have started.
I have no clue why this is only necessary on one node, and not on the other two's. There is the line commented and not set to a specific value.
